# Not able to download an image using www class in unity android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to download an image using this code in my unity project my an android game.

```
    public static Texture2D userTexture=new Texture2D(64, 64, TextureFormat.DXT5, false); //TextureFormat must be DXT5
    public static IEnumerator UserPictureCallback(){
        Debug.Log("USerPicture called");
        FbDebug.Log("USerPicture called");
        WWW url = new WWW("http://i1.wp.com/a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png?resize=64%2C64");


        yield return url;
        //profilePic.renderer.material.mainTexture = textFb2;

        Debug.Log(url);
        url.LoadImageIntoTexture(userTexture);
        Debug.Log("Working");
    }
```

And then I am trying to draw it in GUI using DrawTexture.

```
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(5,0,50,50),FB.userTexture,ScaleMode.StretchToFill, false, 0.0f);
```

But the image texture is not getting downloaded or at least it is not showing in the GUI. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: And you are calling UserPictureCallback with StartCoroutine? And do you get that "Working" debug msg? You could also use isDone etc properties to find out more : http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Having tried this code, it works just fine. So there must be something you're not showing us. Can you show what the rest of your code looks like and how you're calling it? The only "problem" is that the image turns out pink with DXT5, instead of the correct green as shown with RGBA32.

Comment: Hey @Bart I tried to use RGBA32 format but drawtexture didn't showed anything in that case. But when I tried to make RGB24 I got this pixeletted pic (I am sharing the link of the screenshot). So right now I am not sure whether this is a problem of the format or the image itself is not getting downloaded. Please have a look at the below link and help me with this doubt. If the format is incorrect then tell me the right texture to use.


https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29386849/2013-11-25%2000.35.12.png

Comment: @radical yes buddy as you see in the code above I have written the yield exactly like given in the unity scripting manual link you mentioned. And no I don't think I am getting "working" in debug. But I am also having doubts whether I am able to read all the debugs or not since Unity 4.2 :P
I think all the debugs gets printed in tag of unity itself in verbose. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem. I was creating an scrollable image gallery in Unity, where images are downloaded in real-time from the a web server. On iOS devices I was reaching very fast the memory limit (with consequent app crash). That was caused due to a very big number of www objects leaved in the memory and never deleted or released. Also a very big number of Texture2D objects leaked.
The main misunderstanding is considering a Texture2D like a variable of an object that self-contained the image information. Texture2D only point to a referenced asset so we need to create one before assigning to our GUI object. Without creating one we will overwrite the referenced asset in our project, leading to very crazy behaviour.
So this the code that works for me on iOS and just use the minimum of memory

```
    public void DownloadImage(string url)
    {   
        StartCoroutine(coDownloadImage(url));
    }

    IEnumerator coDownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {

        WWW www = new WWW( imageUrl );

        yield return www;

        thumbnail.mainTexture = new Texture2D(www.texture.width, www.texture.height, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(thumbnail.mainTexture as Texture2D);
        www.Dispose();
        www = null;
    }
```

A brief comment:
You receive a url you will download the image from.
Start the coroutine that manage the download
Create the www object in the local scope
yield waiting the download to complete
Create a new Texture2D object/asset with parameters and assign to your final object mainTexture or what do you want
Use the "www.LoadImageIntoTexture()" function to COPY the image inside the created asset (this is the fundamental part)
Dispose and set to null the www object to prevent memory leaking or orphans

Hope it helps who will face the same problem.

An interesting lecture is this website where they implement a WebImageCache system to avoid re-downloading the same image many times.

http://studiofive27.com/index.php/unity-cached-web-images/